# Casting date 'yyyy-mm-dd' from a Widget to a timestamp error

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have a widget called 'filedate' where you can specify a date, were you enter the date in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd', my example will use '2019-10-01' .

I get the value from the widget with the following:

```
val fileloaddate = dbutils.widgets.get("filedate")
```

If I print the fileloaddate, it shows 2019-10-01, I need to use it in a query so if I do a 'select to_timestamp(${fileloaddate}, "yyyy-mm-dd")' it errors as it's seeing the variable as '((2019 - 8) -18). If I cast the string to a date, for example

```
select to_timestamp(to_date(${prundate}), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

with the error of 'cannot resolve 'CAST(((2019 - 8) - 18) AS DATE)'

```
select to_timestamp(to_date('2019-10-01'), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

works fine. I have googled around the answer but can't seem to see what I doing wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure DataBrick you can use getArgument to convert date into desire output

```
dbutils.widgets.text("x","2018-09-12")
select to_timestamp(to_date(getArgument("x")), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

If Scala is disabled then you need to use the legacy method for retrieving sql parameters from widgets
.
select * from database where parameter='$file'

For sql I can pass the date as a text

%sql
create widget 'StartDate' DEFAULT 'YYYY-MM-DD' (this is simply text to remind the user to input the date in a format the sql query can use)

select * from my_table Between '$StartDate' and '$EndDate'

https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html#legacy-input
https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html